# finding combinations of elements from two matrices

Tags: r, combinations

I would like a matrix of all the combinations of

```
matrix1 <- combinations(10,3)
matrix2 <- combinations(20,1)
```

i.e. we are choosing 3 numbers without repetition from a bag with numbers 1 to 10, then one number from 1 to 20

Comment: What packages are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
matrix1 <- combn(10, 3)
matrix2 <- combn(20, 1)

res <- c(
  outer(
    1:ncol(matrix1),
    1:ncol(matrix2),
    Vectorize(function(x, y) list(c(matrix1[, x], matrix2[, y])))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `combinations` does something similar to `utils::combn`, you can use

```
matrix1 <- combn(10, 3)
matrix2 <- combn(20, 1)

pasted1 <- apply(matrix1,2,paste0,collapse=",")
pasted2 <- apply(matrix2,2,paste0,collapse=",")

expanded <- apply(expand.grid(pasted1,pasted2),1,paste0,collapse=",")

res <- lapply(strsplit(expanded,","),as.numeric)
```